# C# TCP Listener from a backgroundworker

Tags: c#, backgroundworker, tcplistener

I have this very simple code snippet in which a simple TCP listener is created.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TCPListenerTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            IPAddress localAddr = IPAddress.Any;
            TcpListener server = null;
            bool done = false;

            server = new TcpListener(localAddr, 5081);
            server.Start();
            while (!done)
            {
                // Perform a blocking call to accept requests.
                // You could also use server.AcceptSocket() here.
                TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();

                //Connected!!
                Console.WriteLine("Connected");
                client.Close();
                done = true;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Done");
            Console.WriteLine("\nHit enter to continue...");
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this code in a Console Application or in a Windows Form everything is fine, i.e. The listener accepts a connection from a client.

When I place this code inside a backgroundworker_DoWork, the client is unable to connect.

I wonder whether there is some issue when usingTCPListener from Backgroundworker.

EDIT: You were right, the TCP Listener works fine inside the background worker.

The code below works fine.
It sends a command (http:///config.cgi?F=8&A=) to an embedded board to start a file transfer.
The board acts as a client. It first request the total number of bytes and the number of packets it will receive. Successively the board sends a request for each packet until the full transfer is done.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TCPListenerBackgroundWorkerTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        String HostIP = "192.168.0.14";
        String BoardIP = "192.168.0.144";
        String pacchettozzoDest = "Italiano.bin";

        void flasherase()
        {
            byte[] stream;

            String cgireq = String.Format("http://{0}/config.cgi?F=8&A={1}", BoardIP, HostIP);          
            try
            {
                WebClient wClient = new WebClient();
                stream = wClient.DownloadData(cgireq);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }


        void updateProcess()
        {
            try
            {
                int updateProg;
                int readBytes;
                int n1 = 0;
                int n2 = 0;
                int PAYLOADSIZE = 1000;
                int HEADERSIZE = 8;
                UInt32 UpdateLength = 0;
                int UpdatePackets = 0;
                bool updateDone = false;
                System.IO.FileStream messFile;
                FileStream sr;

                TcpListener server = null;
                
                messFile = new FileStream(pacchettozzoDest, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                UpdateLength = (UInt32)messFile.Length;
                UpdatePackets = (int)(UpdateLength / PAYLOADSIZE);
                messFile.Close();
                if ((UpdatePackets * PAYLOADSIZE) < UpdateLength)
                    UpdatePackets++;

                server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 5081);
                //Allocate Buffer fore reading data
                byte[] TXbuffer = new byte[256];
                byte[] RXbuffer = new byte[1024];
                // Start listening for client requests.
                server.Start();

                // Perform a blocking call to accept requests.
                // You could also use server.AcceptSocket() here.
                TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
                //Connected!!
                // Get a stream object for reading and writing
                NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

                while (!updateDone)
                {
                    

                    readBytes = stream.Read(RXbuffer, 0, RXbuffer.Length);

                    if (readBytes >= HEADERSIZE)
                    {
                        if (RXbuffer[1] == 0xBE && RXbuffer[0] == 0xEA && RXbuffer[7] == 0xFC && RXbuffer[6] == 0xCF)
                        {
                            n1 = (RXbuffer[3] << 8) + RXbuffer[2];
                            n2 = (RXbuffer[5] << 8) + RXbuffer[4];
                            // First Packet
                            if (0 == n1 && 0 == n2)
                            {
                                byte[] bufferTX = new byte[HEADERSIZE];
                                bufferTX[1] = 0xBE; bufferTX[0] = 0xEA;
                                bufferTX[3] = (byte)((UpdatePackets & 0xFF00) >> 8);
                                bufferTX[2] = (byte)((UpdatePackets & 0xFF));

                                bufferTX[4] = (byte)((UpdateLength & 0x000000FF));
                                bufferTX[5] = (byte)((UpdateLength & 0x0000FF00) >> 8);
                                bufferTX[6] = (byte)((UpdateLength & 0x00FF0000) >> 16);
                                bufferTX[7] = (byte)((UpdateLength & 0xFF000000) >> 24);

                                stream.Write(bufferTX, 0, 8);
                                updateProg = 0;
                            }
                            else if (n1 > 0 && 0 == n2)
                            {
                                byte[] bufferTX = new byte[PAYLOADSIZE + HEADERSIZE];

                                bufferTX[0] = 0xEA;
                                bufferTX[1] = 0xBE;

                                bufferTX[2] = (byte)((n1 & 0xFF));
                                bufferTX[3] = (byte)((n1 & 0xFF00) >> 8);

                                updateProg = (n1 * 100) / UpdatePackets;

                                sr = File.OpenRead(pacchettozzoDest);
                                sr.Seek((n1 - 1) * PAYLOADSIZE, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                                int readB = 0;
                                int PaySize = 0;
                                for (int p = 0; p < PAYLOADSIZE; p++)
                                {
                                    readB = sr.ReadByte();
                                    if (readB != -1)
                                    {
                                        bufferTX[p + 6] = (byte)readB;
                                        PaySize++;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }

                                bufferTX[4] = (byte)((PaySize & 0xFF));
                                bufferTX[5] = (byte)((PaySize & 0xFF00) >> 8);

                                bufferTX[6 + PAYLOADSIZE] = 0xCF;
                                bufferTX[6 + PAYLOADSIZE + 1] = 0xFC;
                                sr.Close();

                                stream.Write(bufferTX, 0, (PAYLOADSIZE + HEADERSIZE));
                                updateProg = 0;
                            }
                            //End
                            else if ((0xFFFF == n1) && (0xFFFF == n2))
                            {
                                // Shutdown and end connection
                                client.Close();
                                updateProg = 100;
                                updateDone = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }

        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            IPAddress localAddr = IPAddress.Any;
            TcpListener server = null;
            bool done = false;


            flasherase();

            updateProcess();

            MessageBox.Show("Done");                        
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("BKGRW Completed");
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `When I place this code inside a backgroundworker_DoWork, the client is unable to connect`, in the above code, you don't have any code related to a backgroundworker. Please update your post to include what you're inquiring about as of right now, the code above is irrelevant to what you're asking about. How can we replicate the issue you're having?

Comment: No.  The issue is either you are not calling code to start listener or you disposing the listener when you leave the method where it started.  In the console application you block  with the Console.Read() so you do not exit.  You have to make sure something similar is being done in the worker.

Comment: Thank you Codexer, jdweng. The problem was the listener was disposed.